# addClass to modal checkout from third party script (payment processor)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal checkout for my payment processor (Lemon Squeezy) and I have control over when this happens via the checkout button, the CSS is loaded from the payment processors script. I'm trying to have a JS/jQuery function that will listen for this checkout element to appear (.ls-checkout) and then apply custom styles via addClass or just applying inline CSS. I have tried variations of things using MutationObserver API, the .on() method, and nothing is working.

I'm not sure if there is something special about my circumstance that requires some specific method that I don't know about, or I'm just doing the wrong thing.

Since I can't give a working jsfiddle for this, here is a live website that uses the same payment processor/modal checkout. just click the Buy button to trigger..no account sign up is required.  https://landify.design/landify-ui

Any tips on the best method to do what I need? Thanks

addClass to modal checkout from third party script (payment processor)

Comment: It's really hard to see what you're looking for without including your code here. Please add a minimal reproducible example to your post. But based on what I think I'm understanding, could you just include the required css on the page and then when the checkout element appears, it would be styled as indicated.

Comment: @mykaf I have put the CSS in multiple ways with !important and it still doesn't apply, so I just assumed I was gonna have to do something to apply it after the canvas is visible.

I'll try to reproduce it in a fiddle of possible. But the link I posted is the same as what I'm seeing more or less.

Comment: The thing is, links to fiddles break; post a minimal reproducible example in your original post, preferably as a snippet. We don't need to wade through your entire code to pinpoint the problem. It honestly sounds like a CSS problem to me.